# Adding prefix to existing URLs in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The Problem: I am implementing a localization feature in my web application, but the application is in mid-development, so to not rewrite all the links in `<form action="">` and `<a href="">` I need a solution that would just add a prefix tu URLs before all other routes like /en/ or /es/, but that Application would consider /localhost/en/ as localhost/.

To clearify link like `<a href="/admin">` is working as advertised http://localhost/admin, I need it to work like http://localhost/en/admin

I dont know what pieces of code is any help, so I will add code on request.

route.php looks something like this

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('admin/blocks/{size}', "AdminController@getBlocks");
Route::get('admin/del-block/{id}', "AdminController@getDelBlock");


Route::controllers([
    'admin' => 'AdminController',
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    'products' => 'ProductsController'
]);
Route::get('/{slug}', "HomeController@getPage");
Route::get('/{slug}/{subslug}', "HomeController@getPage");
```

and in views I generate URLs by hand

```
<a href="/admin/blocks{{$block->size}}">Link</a>
<form action="/products/new" > </form>
```

Comment: Here is a good example to add localization https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website

Comment: @KamranAdil did all that, that doesn't help, all routes are still broken

Comment: You have to provide more info. What have you tried? Show us your routes file and how you generate your URL's on your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `http://localhost/admin` and `http://localhost/en/admin` to be handled by same controllers then you need to write 2 sets of routes in `routes.php`.

This way there are 2 entry points to exactly same application logic.

First entry point for non-localized url: `/admin`. Second would take a parameter: `{lang}/admin`.

Comment: but /en/ could be any of ISO 2 character country codes, it is not logical, that I would need X sets of routes??? and if languages ar added dynamicaly, then its not even possible